# help with normal linear operators and projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

help, I don't know how to try the following

1. if T is an isometry then $TT^\star$it's a projection
2. if T, S are two normal operators  $ST=TS$ and S is compact , then $S+T$ and $ST$  They are normal.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: It will help to write out the definition of a projection and normal operator. The first problem, at least, should be immediate from the definition.

Comment: The second problem is immediate as well, and the assumption that $S$ is compact is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

$P=T^*T$ is an orthogonal projection iff $P^2=P=P^*$. To show this, using $T^*T=I$,
$$
        (TT^*)^2=T(T^*T)T^*=TT^* \\
        (TT^*)^*= TT^*
$$